# Monitor for photo/art display?

Tags: monitors

What would be the best display type for a wall mounted monitor that rotates photographs and artworks as an aesthetic piece? Is there anything that works well with glare and also lacks the telltale backlighting they gives most monitors away?

Comment: Do you have any screen size and resolution requirements? I am assuming full color support is a must (to eliminate e-ink displays). What about power and connection requirements? Price? Is there anything else that you can think of that might help us narrow down the selection?

Comment: I'd say e-ink is out due to resolution/color constraints. Really no other contraints: just trying to determine best display technology for simulating real word printed/painted pieces. OLED?

Comment: What are your price requirements like?